# "had been" vs "were"

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect, past-simple

Could you please tell me what is the difference between these two sentences?

> There **had also been** reports that rival gangs of youths **had been seen**
>   throwing fireworks at each other near the warehouses, and this might
>   also have had something to do with the fire starting.
>
> There **were also** reports that rival gangs of youths **were seen** throwing
>   fireworks at each other near the warehouses, and this might also have
>   had something to do with the fire starting.

Answer (score 2):

Both

> have been
>   were

both talk about something in the past, and in your particular example have no difference in meaning.

However, without further context

> there had been reports

is usually more general and nonspecific

> There had been reports by various sources....

where as

> there were reports

is usually more specific and concrete

> There were reports by witnesses that...

The subtlety may change with additional context